# PHP - mysqli_fetch_field equivalent for PostgreSQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I'm trying to move to my project to PostgreSQL from MySQL. For MySQL, PHP offers good functionality to fetch SELECT query metadata.

`mysqli_fetch_field` or `mysqli_fetch_field_direct` functions can give the following values for each field in the query

- name
- orgname
- table
- orgtable
- max_length
- length
- type
- (and a few others I'm not interested in currently)

For instance, an example query and metadata for the field "id" frm the query will look like this:

Query:

> SELECT id as id2 FROM table1 t1

Metadata for field "id" :

- name: id2
- orgname : id
- table : t1
- orgtable : table1
- length: 765
- type: 253

The good thing about `mysqli_fetch_field` is that it is capable of returning both alias and original name of the fields and tables in the query.

When I try to imitate this functionality for PostgreSQL, I observe that there is no equivalent of `mysqli_fetch_field` function for PostgreSQL, instead, there are several pg_field_* functions each of which give a single information for a field.

- `pg_field_name` returns name only and for this example it gives "id2"
- `pg_field_table` returns original table name, e.g. "table1"
- `pg_field_type` returns the type (no problem here)
- `pg_field_size` returns the length of the field (it is also OK)

Obviously, pg_field_* functions do not offer the programmer original names of the tables/fields if they are renamed in the query while `mysqli_fetch_field` does.

Is there a way that I can fetch "detailed" metadata for a query in PostgreSQL? It can be using an additional query or a tool that the DBMS offers like EXPLAIN and DESCRIBE (I tried these too) or anything else.

Comment: It was a mistake, sorry. I updated the post with mysqli_* functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I am eventually convinced that neither PHP Postgres API nor PostreSQL itself provides such functionality. Therefore, I could manage to solve the problem by a combination of pg_field_* functions and an SQL Parser written in PHP, namely [PHP-SQL-Parser](https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser)

Even though the SQL parser is written MySQL in mind, the default functionality worked for my use case and it is extensible in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you invested into the Postgres specific function API? If not, check out [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo), which provides you one common interface to your database, no matter if it is MySQL or Postgres. It also provides you a way to fetch specific columns:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = ?");
$statement->execute([42]);
$foo = $statement->fetchColumn(0);
// $foo is the column value or false
```

You can also fetch column values of all result rows:

```
$foos = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
// $foos is an array, possibly empty
```

Note that `fetchAll` incurs the usual memory penalty, as a possibly large result is loaded into your process. You should only use `fetchAll` if the result set is known to always be small. Otherwise, use `fetch` or `fetchColumn` in a loop and page the query with `LIMIT n, m` clauses.

Fetching a specific column is resource friendly if only one column is queried. When you have other columns in your query, they would still be fetched into your process, just to be thrown away. You should make sure to not include any unnecessary columns.

For column *metadata*, use [getColumnMeta](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php):

```php
$meta = $statement->getColumnMeta(0);
// $meta is false or array{native_type, driver:decl_type, flags, name, table, len, precision, pdo_type}
```

To get more detailed metadata, you should query into [information_schema.columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table). Best to do it before the data query, because the data query might be executed in a loop. Metadata need to be fetched only once beforehand.

Comment: This does look like related to fetching column values not the metadata.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, it still looks like PDO does not give "name" and "original" name of the field in case field/table is renamed with an alias. If it does, please correct me.

Comment: This specific use case is not covered by either PDO or PG function API. You will have to do it on your own. For example, PDO API is rather low-level. I ended up creating an adapter API, which allowed me to do stuff such as multi-database transactions. In your adapter, you could analyze the query (preg_match or whatever) and see if there is a rename.

Comment: Analyzing query via preg_match would be hard and error prone. Nonetheless, there are libraries/packages available to this specific purpose. I can use them if I cannot find a solution via PostgreSQL queries/tool and PHP API options.

Comment: I wonder how these packages do it. Unless they use the raw Postgres connection and do some protocol fu, I imagine they'd have to analyze the query as well. Re "it's hard and and error prone" I don't quite see that. It may involve some non-zero effort and a unit test, but on the other hand you get control over a critical infrastructural component (database access layer).